# Popup buttons appearing on all pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a popup that looks exactly how I want it but the heading and buttons are appearing on all pages.  If i remove the `ui-title` class in the heading it will no longer appear but does not look how i want it to.  If i remove the `ui-btn-inner` and `ui-btn` classes the buttons will no longer appear in all pages but the styling is off again.  How can I keep this styling but not have the buttons and heading appear on all pages?

Here is the popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Create Location Page?</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-d" role="main">
        <h3 class="ui-title">You are about to create a new Location?</h3>
        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true"  class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-c">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">Cancel</span></span>
        </a>    
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"  data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-b">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">Create</span></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The popup is triggered to appear after calling this:

```
    function PopupTest(){
        $('#popupDialog').popup();
        $('#popupDialog').popup("open");
    }
```

Comment: what if you add "display:none" to the style of popupDialog? does the popup still work?

Comment: which are the pages you want it to appear.

Comment: Is your popup markup within your [page wrapper](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/)?

Comment: @malificent `$('#popupDialog').css("display","none");` doesnt do anything;  @jaipsah i want it to only appear on `NearbyLocationsPage` of my multipage webpage after clicking a button that calls `PopupTest()`;  @Jack the popup is not with the page wrapper, should it?

Comment: @Jack moving the popup into the page wrapper did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't to clear in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html) for the popup widget but according to [blog post](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/) for the jQuery Mobile 1.2 release, for the moment the popup widget must be in the page wrapper, but that in a future release this should no longer be necessary.

Here's the relevant text

> **Popups must live within the page wrapper (for now)**
>
> After alpha went out, we also heard pretty clear feedback that folks
>   want to re-use popups across pages by placing them outside the page
>   container. At the moment this won’t work because many widgets
>   (listviews, toolbars) are built with the assumption that they live
>   inside a page container for theme inheritance and enhancement to work.
>   Until these widgets are re-factored to work outside of pages at a
>   future release, popups should only be added within a page.

Answer (score 0):

By moving my popup within the page wrappers of the page i want it to exist, the popup will only appear on pages I want.